# How is DNS reliable when it uses UDP protocol at transport layer?

Tags: networking, dns, udp

I have searched the same and got something like this:

"An application can use UDP and can be reliable by using timeout and resend at application layer."

Does reliability only means sending acknowledgments and what about identifying corrupted/duplicate packets?
Can anybody explain me the depth of this.

Comment: This is not a place to ask such questions, please refrain from asking general questions which are not related to programming. Please read "What topics can I ask about here?". A second visit to the tour would also enlighten you on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDP not being reliable means that UDP does not care itself that the packet is received by the peer, ordering of packets, duplicates etc.

But, an application layer protocol can itself care about this and does not need to rely on the reliability of the lower layer. In case of DNS each request should lead to exactly one response and receiving the response is implicitly the acknowledgment that the request was received. Also a DNS request and response each fit into a single UDP packet - so reordering does not matter. Each UDP request has a unique combination of ID and source port and the response packet contains the same ID and port - so it is clear which response belongs to which query. And if a response is not received within some time it will assume that it either the request or the response are lost and simply retry with a new query.

Comment: was I wrong in flagging the question.? Is this question suitable for stack overflow?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar: It is hard to tell where such question really belong. It is not about programming by itself but it is about understanding of concepts which might be relevant for programming. I don't see any stackexchange site where such questions fit better, even though I don't think it is a perfect fit here.  There is [networkengineering.se] but they don't care about application layer and thus the question would be off-topic there. And there are already several such conceptional questions here which are not strictly about programming.

Comment: And besides this very good reply, note that nowadays the world is shifting towards DNS over HTTPS or over TLS, which are based off TCP. (there is DNS over QUIC around the corner too, where QUIC is closer to UDP than TCP but then with the TLS guarantees). DNS replies being larger than a single UDP packet created a lot of problems, hence the EDNS extension. Interestingly, have a look at https://dnsflagday.net/

Comment: Your answer is the best relatable and simply answer I've found so far all over the internet; deserves more credit than its being given. Thanks +1